# How to fetch data by clicking element

Tags: javascript

I would like to fetch data by clicking button.

current My work is like below code.

Are there any way to bind this?

Thanks

```js
var apikey="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=multiple";

fetch(apikey)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
        console.log(json);
  });
```

```html
<button type="button">get data</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event listener on the `click` of the button which uses your code:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
     var apikey="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=multiple";
     fetch(apikey)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => {
               console.log(json);
          });
})
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button">get data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

bind on click function.

```js
async function fetchData(){
    var apikey="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=multiple";

    let data =  await fetch(apikey)
      .then(response => response.json());
      
    console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="fetchData()">get data</button>
```